# Size parameter in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

It may be a beginner question, but I have some doubts related to size.
As per elastic search specs, the maximum value of size can be 10000, I want to validate my understandings below:

Sample Query:

```
GET testindex-2016.04.14/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "TEST"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "testAggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "innerAggs": {
          "max": {
            "field": "Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 26949,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
       .....10000 records   
     ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "test": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "TEST",
          "doc_count": 26949,
          "innerAggs": {
            "value": 150
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

1 - If size is set to 10000, and we have more than 200000 records in elastic search satisfying the query, So in query result, I will get the no. of hits to 10000, but the "total" : 200000.

2 - How many records will be available for further aggregations - the no. of hits or the "total" value.

3 - If we set "size" : 0, in this case, we get hits = 0, but how many records will be available for aggregations ?

Please clarify my understanding, and put comments in any doubt in question . Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. The `size` parameter only tells how many hits should be returned in the response, so if you specify size: 10000 and 200000 records match, you'll get 10000 matching documents in the result hits, but `total` will state 200000
2. aggregations are always computed on the full set of results, so the `total` value.
3. See 2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew that I will get answer from you, So I have one more doubt- Is there any upper limit on the "total" value, I mean the query and aggregations run on all the matching records, regardless of the number.

Comment: No upper limit except a physical one, which is the number of total documents that a shard can contain (=Integer.MAX_VALUE).